# Problem fetching data from an API with axios in React: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

This should be simple, but I don't know why it is failing.

I'm fetching data from an API with axios in React. The code is really simple:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://dummyjson.com/products/")
      .then((response) => {
        setItems(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  console.log(items);
}
```

This works right, and I get the response in the console:

[image: console log]

Now, if I change `console.log(error);`  to  `console.log(error.products);` at first works and I can see it also in the console:

[image: console log 2]

But, if I reload the page it stops working and shows error:

[image: error screen]

I have tried with the fetch inside and outside of `useEffect`, two `useEffects`, API `fetch` instead of Axios, but is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

On the first render, the component sees the init state as undefined. Try to conditionally render all the components:

```
if(!items) return null

return the rest
```

Or, the easy solution, use an array as the initial state:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
```

Comment: I could swear I had already tried using array as the initial state....... something else did wrong then. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify whether the item is undefined. This is because, when reloading, the promise is still incomplete. A straightforward way to do this is:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react"
import axios from "axios";


function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
      axios.get("https://dummyjson.com/products/")

          .then((response) => {
              setItems(response.data);
          }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  if (items === undefined) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else if (items) {
    console.log(items.products);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works. I knew that the promise was incomplete, but I don't understand why it completes with items but not with items.products. Any hint??

Comment: I think you will get errors in both cases, accessing items.products directly can cause an error if items is still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code. I hope this helps!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      await axios
        .get("https://dummyjson.com/products/")
        .then((response) => {
          setItems(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {items?.products &&
        items?.products.map((item) => <p key={item.id}>{item.title}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You App component should return JSX like this:

```js
return (
    <div>
      {items &&
        items.products.map((product) => (
          <div key={product.id}>{product.title}</div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Why? Because on initial render your `items` state's `undefined` so JS couldn't read products property of undefined and gave an error you mentioned. To avoid this, you need to check `items` for **falsy** value like above code.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be related to the initial state of items. When you initialize items using const [items, setItems] = useState(), its initial value is undefined. When you try to access error.products in the catch block, it works the first time because there's no data, and error itself is undefined. However, after the initial successful API call, the state is updated with the actual data, and subsequent API calls are not hitting the catch block, resulting in error being undefined.

**You can initialize items with an empty array or an empty object instead of undefined. This way, even if there's no data, items won't be undefined.**

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue with fetching data, but rather an issue with not maintaining a valid state invariant.

The `items` state is initially undefined, so from the initial render cycle until it ***is*** defined, attempting to access properties from it will result in the thrown exception. You can see this in the screen shot where the first `console.log(items)` outputs `undefined`, then after the state is updated, `console.log(items)` outputs the response.data object.

If all you really are interested in storing and rendering is the `products` array, then I suggest the following refactor:

1. Start with a defined, initially empty, `items` array in state.
2. Update `items` with the `response.data.products` array value.

This allows the code to maintain the invariant that `items` is an array.

```
export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]); // <-- initial empty array

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://dummyjson.com/products/")
      .then((response) => {
        setItems(response.data.products); // <-- save products array
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  console.log(items);

  ...
}
```

Now when this code runs you will see one `console.log(items)` that is the initial empty array, and then later a `console.log(items)` that is the fetched products array.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://dummyjson.com/products/")
      .then((response) => setItems(response.data.products))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  console.log(items);
  
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          {[item.title, item.price].join(" - ")}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.6.2/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-b94Z6431JyXY14iSXwgzeZurHHRNkLt9d6bAHt7BZT38eqV+GyngIi/tVye4jBKPYQ2lBdRs0glww4fmpuLRwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="root" />
```